# Exception-handling antipatterns

Tags: exception

Exception handling is a challenge for new and experienced developers alike. What are some examples of exception handling antipatterns that people have seen?

Answer (score 3):

**Bad cleanup logic**

Throwing in clean up code from a destructor. This one is doubly bad, because a.) throwing from a destructor is generally bad and b.) because even if you could catch it, there isn't anything to do about it.

```
File::~File()
{
    if (!close(fd_)) {
        throw FileIOException("Could not close descriptor.", fd_);
    }
}
```

**The UI from hell**

```
 try {
    // ... lots of UI logic here ...
 } catch (Exception error) {
    alert("This program has performed an illegal operation and needs to quit.");
    System.exit(-1);
 }
```

**Retrying without backoff**

```
 bool has_connected = false;
 while (!has_connected) {
     try {
        EstablishConnection();
        has_connected = true;
     } catch (...) {
        // IGNORE
     }
  }
```

Comment: Retrying without backoff can turn a performance issue into an availability issue. Good one.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that isn't entirely unlike things that I've seen before.

```
try {
    methodThatThrowsSomeException1();
    methodThatThrowsSomeOtherException2();
    methodThatThrowsSomeOtherException3();
    methodThatThrowsSomeOtherException4();
    methodThatThrowsSomeOtherException5();
    methodThatThrowsSomeOtherException6();
    ...
    methodThatThrowsYetAnotherException20();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error("There was a problem reading the user role");
    role = PRIVILEGED;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`catch (...)` in C++.

Probably the worst way to make your code look stable...

The same applies to any other language, where you catch exceptions you don't expect, and just swallow them silently in order to hide the error from the user. But the `(...)` is usually used to catch exceptions such as NULL pointer dereference or access denials, which means the error swallowed will probably manifest itself later in ways that might look totaly unrelated to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My biggest pet peeve is setting up an exception inheritance hierarchy in which descendant relationships provide little bearing upon whether an exception should be caught or not.  There's not much do be done about pre-defined exceptions, but my preference is to avoid throwing those and instead define new exceptions for cases where the caller should assume that the system state is fine except to the extent implied by the fact that the routine didn't return successfully, versus those where the system state is trashed.  For example, if a method is supposed to open a file and return a new document object, but there's some problem parsing the file, it shouldn't kill the whole application.  It should let the user know the file couldn't be opened, and then proceed as though the user hadn't tried to open the file.  It's irrelevant why the file didn't open; the question is whether application state has been corrupted.  Unfortunately, none of the standard exceptions are very good at dealing with that.

Comment: Perhaps that is because not being able to open a file is not really an exceptional event? Shouldn't this be part of regular error-handling?

Comment: @Sedate Alien: Sometimes it should be exception, sometimes not; that's what the Try/Do pattern is for.  Within a parsing routine, however, one would typically use exceptions to abort an unsuccessful parse, rather than test every single sub-operation for success.  It would not be uncommon for error-checking to almost double the length of a parsing routine; if the only thing the error check would do is abort the parse, using exceptions can practically cut the code size in half.

Answer (score 1):

Using exceptions in shared libraries that are meant to be used from multiple languages / C++ dialects. Since there's no way the C++ compiler can guarantee you aren't accidentally throwing an exception back to the caller (unlike in Java) you're just setting yourself up for a crash.